# Define map inside name space

Tags: javascript

Trying to define global map inside namespace and access that inside those namespace functions. but keep on getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier. Appreciated If any one could guide me in defining global map inside namespace function and accessing.

```
var namespace = {
  var mymap = new map();
  cm: function () {       
    var childContainer = $("<div>");        
    namespace.myMap.set(cc, childContainer);
  },
  hm: function(ccm, data){          
    var cMenuItem = ccm.innerHTML;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.c.length; ++i){
      if ( cMenuItem === data.c[i]['l']){     
        namespace.Menus(data.c[i]);  
        namespace.myMap.get(cc);     
      }
    }   
  }
};
```

Error comes in the first line `var mymap = new map();` as `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Comment: `map` is not the same as `Map`. [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: Ok. Will change and check

Comment: Still the same error , Is any other way to define Map() inside namespace.

Comment: If namespace is an object you should use the `myMap: new Map()` syntax instead of `=` as you are declaring a field in an object. Didn't see it in your original question. Do take a good look at referencing `namespace` in the declaration of itself.

Comment: yup got it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring a `var` inside an object. You cannot do that. You can only declare variables in a function.

What you did:

```
var namespace = {
  var mymap = new map();  // <------ this line
  cm: function () {       
    var childContainer = $("<div>");        
    namespace.myMap.set(cc, childContainer);
  },
  hm: function(ccm, data){          
    var cMenuItem = ccm.innerHTML;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.c.length; ++i){
      if ( cMenuItem === data.c[i]['l']){     
        namespace.Menus(data.c[i]);  
        namespace.myMap.get(cc);     
      }
    }   
  }
};
```

What you should do:

```
var namespace = {
  mymap: new map();  // <----- this line
  cm: function () {       
    var childContainer = $("<div>");        
    namespace.myMap.set(cc, childContainer);
  },
  hm: function(ccm, data){          
    var cMenuItem = ccm.innerHTML;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.c.length; ++i){
      if ( cMenuItem === data.c[i]['l']){     
        namespace.Menus(data.c[i]);  
        namespace.myMap.get(cc);     
      }
    }   
  }
};
```

Besides, `map()` is not `Map()`, as mentioned in comment.

Comment: Yup. var mymap = new map();   works for me and end its not semicolon since object , will come